# Run JavaScript in WebView while page is still Loading - Can I get Progress Percentage?

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview

I've been trying to get a javascript function to run in my `WebView` by calling `webView.loadUrl('javascript:...')` in the `onPageFinished` method of `WebViewClient`. However this is too late for the proper effects of the javascript function to be seen.

My question is is there a way to call `loadUrl` slightly before `onPageFinished` Possibly by monitoring the progress of loading in a while loop and call it then? Can you even see the progress percentage of a `WebView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WebChromeClient` can be used to monitor web page loading progress and as such you can perform actions at specific times with this. I didn't use this in the end however.

Answer (score 0):

You've already marked chris answer. But i have a question. Why do not use the javascriptinterface at this point, i think this is the easiest way to go...

Comment: I did - I didn't write that in the answer as it didn't answer the question I asked. Thanks anyway though

Comment: ahhh, questioner == answerer...now i got it, too! :-)